# Por que me genera error PathAccessException: Cannot open file

Tags: flutter

Estoy usando el paquete permission_handler para los permisos, external_path para poder escribir en el almacenamiento externo y open_file para abrir un archivo.
El problema es que me genera error de PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/nombreArchivo.pdf' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13) pero antes de generar y guardar el archivo, hago el pedido del permiso que se va a usar, en este caso, almacenamiento externo.

```
    final permissionProvider =
        Provider.of<PermissionProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await _attendanceProvider.getListAttendance(dateSelectText);
    List<AttendanceViewModel> reportAttendanceDayList =
        _attendanceProvider.attendanceViewModelList;
    String htmlContent = '''
<style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
    <h1>Reporte diario de asistencias</h1>
    <p>Fecha: $dateSelectText</p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Numero Trabajador</th>
                <th>Nombre del Trabajador</th>
                <th>Hora de Entrada</th>
                <th>Hora de Salida</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ${buildTableHTMLAttendanceDay(reportAttendanceDayList)}
        </tbody>
    </table>''';
    final pdf = pdfh.Document();
    final widgets = await pdfh.HTMLToPdf().convert(htmlContent);
    pdf.addPage(
      pdfh.MultiPage(
        maxPages: 200,
        build: (context) {
          return widgets;
        },
      ),
    );

    String fileName = 'lista_de_asistencia_$dateSelectText.pdf';

    final String filePath = await obtainFilePath(fileName);

    File file = File(filePath);

    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();
    }

    if (permissionProvider.statusPermision) {
      await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
    } else {
      return "Permiso denegado";
    }
    // await openFileFromPath(filePath);
    return filePath;
```

Este es mi metodo para pedir permiso

```
static Future<bool> checkStoragePermissions(Permission permission) async {
    PermissionStatus status = await permission.status;
    if (status.isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      await permission.request();
      status = await permission.status;
      return status.isGranted;
    }
  }
```

Este es el archivo AndroiManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```